# Pandas filter dataframe by single condition across multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 30 columns, each cell containing a 1 or 0.

I would like to filter the dataframe for where any 1 of 4 specific columns == 1.

Right now, it would have to be chained masks like:

```
df[(df['col1'] == 1) | (df['col2'] == 1) | (df['col3'] == 1) | (df['col4'] == 1)]
```

Is there a simpler and scalable way to do this? Something like making a list of the column names, and using slice notation to check all boolean conditions in one go?:

```
col_list = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']

df[df[col_list] == 1]
```

Comment: You want `df = df[df[col_list].eq(1).any(1)]`.

Comment: or `df[df[col_list].any(1)]`

Comment: FYI you would get answers in the *answer section* if you had provided an input to work with.

Comment: @coldspeed amazing thanks for how quickly you answered this!

Comment: @MitchellPosluns hi mitch

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
col_df=list(df) # get all the column names 
filtered_df=df[df[col_df].any(1)]
```

Comment: This would work if I wanted _all_ of the columns to be assessed by the condition, question was for just a subset but the method is the same, thanks!